# Listen for form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to register when a form is submitted on my site, no matter where and when - it may be dynamically loaded or created form - I need to be able to tell whenever **any** form is about to be submitted on the page. Event listeners are simply not an option here for the reasons mentioned above.

I was thinking what other options I have and one of them was like if I would want to capture clicks on buttons for example, I could add a click listener to the document and check `event.target` to determine whether a button has been clicked without adding listeners to every particular button. I was hoping I could do the same with form submissions but I didn't find a suitable event to listen for on a document.

Another solution that came to mind was to extend `HTMLFormElement` prototype and add a default `onclick` function such as

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.onsubmit = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Unfortunately that turned out to be impossible as well, getting various errors in different browsers like

- TypeError: 'set onsubmit' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.
- Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

I'm running out of ideas, is this impossible?

**EDIT**: The question is clearly not a duplicate as I have described in my first idea exactly what is stated in the accepted answer of the suggested question and I do not see how to apply this in my case.

Comment: Why are event listeners not an option? You can get a list of forms on any given page.

Comment: @pvg because how do I know when a form is added to the page? I'm talking about dynamic content.

Comment: It depends on when your code runs? What is the context here? document.forms doesn't care how the forms are added, they'll still be there.

Comment: @pvg Yes but what if a form is created by javascript and gets added to the document, then how would I know that form was added so I attach an event listener to it before the user submits it? Assume I'm not going to be the one writing the page logic.

Comment: @php_nub_qq did you check my answer?

Comment: "but I didn't find a suitable event to listen for on a document" — Err … that's the `submit` event

Comment: Again, the context matters. Is this an extension? Running inside something like phantom? a call to preventDefault in an existing handler can prevent you from catching the event toplevel, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will not work on `snippets` (because snippets don't allow form submission), so I didn't create one, but it will in your site:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Form submitted');
});
$('body').append($('<form action=""><input type="submit" value="Submit dynamic form" /></form>'));
```

> I used the `preventDefault` just to make sure the form will not get submitted. You can remove it in your code.

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dekelb/gr94dg7q/

### update - vanilla javascript solution:

```
document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Form submitted');
});

$('body').append($('<form action=""><input type="submit" value="Submit dynamic form" /></form>'));
```

> Note the relevant javascript (no-jquery) is for the `submit` event, it's not related to the next line (regarding adding a new form to the document).

Comment: That looks like some cool jquery magic but I'm not really looking into using jquery. If you could explain how that works behind the scenes that would be mighty helpful.

Comment: @Check the update

Comment: I'll be damned, I just assumed that wouldn't work, as I said in the question. You could've just said I was wrong :D Anyway big thanks!

Comment: sometimes it's quicker to provide a working example than to argue regarding if something will work or not :)